# What is the Win32::Daemon context hash keyword for delayed auto-start?

Tags: perl, winapi

In [Win32::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Daemon)'s doc, it says:

> `start_type` An integer specifying how (or whether) the service is to be started. The default is SERVICE_AUTO_START.

I don't find anywhere that it says what the value is for *delayed autostart*.

A look at the source behind Win32::Daemon might help but I don't know how to find it. Apparently it's loaded via a perl bootstrap function.

Comment: There's no value you can pass to [`CreateService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx)'s `start_type` that do what you want. You need to call [`ChangeServiceConfig2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx) as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30001192/589924). You could use [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API) to call it.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Daemon-20131206/Daemon.pm under CreateService ( \%ServiceInfo )...start_type

Comment: I repeat: **There's no value you can pass to `CreateService`'s `start_type` that does what you want.** Read [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx)!!!

Comment: sorry, i misread (actually i was reading my own comment without realizing!) and i thought it/you were asking where i saw the statement about start_type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no value you can pass to the `start_type` parameter of [`CreateService()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682450.aspx) that will do what you want. You need to call [`ChangeServiceConfig2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx), as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30001192/589924). You can use [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API) to call it.

Code:

```
use My::Win32::Service qw( :ALL );

my $ServiceName = ...;

my $SCManager;
my $Service ;

if (!eval {
   $SCManager = OpenSCManager(undef, undef, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
      or die("Can't open the service control manager: $^E\n");

   $Service = OpenService($SCManager, $ServiceName, SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG)
      or die("Can't open the service: $^E\n");

   ChangeServiceConfig2($Service, SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO, pack_SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO(1))
      or die("Can't set the service to delayed auto-start: $^E\n");

   CloseServiceHandle($Service);
   CloseServiceHandle($SCManager);

   return 1;  # No exception
}) {
   my $e = $@;
   CloseServiceHandle($Service)   if $Service;
   CloseServiceHandle($SCManager) if $SCManager;
   die($e);
}
```

`My/Win32/Service.pm`:

```
package My::Win32::Service;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( state );

use Encode     qw( decode );
use Exporter   qw( import );
use Win32::API qw( );

our %EXPORT_TAGS;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
   OpenSCManager
   OpenService
   CloseServiceHandle
   ChangeServiceConfig2
   pack_SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO
);

# -----

use constant {
   GENERIC_READ    => 0x80000000,
   GENERIC_WRITE   => 0x40000000,
   GENERIC_EXECUTE => 0x20000000,
   GENERIC_ALL     => 0x10000000,
};

$EXPORT_TAGS{GENERIC} = [qw(
   GENERIC_READ
   GENERIC_WRITE
   GENERIC_EXECUTE
   GENERIC_ALL
)];

use constant {
   STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED => 0xF0000,
};

push @EXPORT_OK, qw(
   STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
);

use constant {
   SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE     => 0x0002,
   SC_MANAGER_CONNECT            => 0x0001,
   SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE  => 0x0004,
   SC_MANAGER_LOCK               => 0x0008,
   SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG => 0x0020,
   SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS  => 0x0010,
};

use constant {
   SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS =>
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
      | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE
      | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT
      | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE
      | SC_MANAGER_LOCK
      | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG
      | SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS,
};

$EXPORT_TAGS{SC_MANAGER} = [qw(
   SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE
   SC_MANAGER_CONNECT
   SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE
   SC_MANAGER_LOCK
   SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG
   SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS
   SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS
)];

use constant {
   SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG        => 0x0002,
   SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS => 0x0008,
   SERVICE_INTERROGATE          => 0x0080,
   SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE       => 0x0040,
   SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG         => 0x0001,
   SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS         => 0x0004,
   SERVICE_START                => 0x0010,
   SERVICE_STOP                 => 0x0020,
   SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL => 0x0100,
};

use constant {
   SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS =>
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
      | SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG
      | SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS
      | SERVICE_INTERROGATE
      | SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE
      | SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG
      | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS
      | SERVICE_START
      | SERVICE_STOP
      | SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL;
};

$EXPORT_TAGS{SERVICE} = [qw(
   SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG
   SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS
   SERVICE_INTERROGATE
   SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE
   SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG
   SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS
   SERVICE_START
   SERVICE_STOP
   SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL
   SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS
)];

use constant {
   SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO  => 3,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION              => 1,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS          => 2,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS_FLAG     => 4,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_PREFERRED_NODE           => 9,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO         => 7,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFO => 6,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO         => 5,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO             => 8,
   SERVICE_CONFIG_LAUNCH_PROTECTED         => 12,
};

$EXPORT_TAGS{SERVICE_CONFIG} = [qw(
   SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO
   SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION
   SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS
   SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS_FLAG
   SERVICE_CONFIG_PREFERRED_NODE
   SERVICE_CONFIG_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO
   SERVICE_CONFIG_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFO
   SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO
   SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO
   SERVICE_CONFIG_LAUNCH_PROTECTED
)];

{
   my %export_ok;
   ++$export_ok{$_}
      for
         @EXPORT_OK,
         ( map {@$_, values %EXPORT_TAGS );

   @EXPORT_OK = sort keys %export_ok;
   $EXPORT_TAGS{ALL} = \@EXPORT_OK;
}

# -----

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx
# typedef int           BOOL;
# typedef unsigned long DWORD;
# typedef PVOID         HANDLE;
# typedef void*         PVOID;

# *** I'm pretty sure some of these are wrong on 64-bit builds of Perl. ***

use constant {
   WAPI_FORMAT_PTR    => 'I',                PACK_FORMAT_PTR    => 'i',
};

use constant {
   WAPI_FORMAT_BOOL   => 'I',                PACK_FORMAT_BOOL   => 'i',
   WAPI_FORMAT_DWORD  => 'N',                PACK_FORMAT_DWORD  => 'L',
   WAPI_FORMAT_HANDLE => WAPI_FORMAT_PVOID,  PACK_FORMAT_HANDLE => PACK_FORMAT_PTR,
};

# -----

sub encode_LPCWSTR {
   my ($s) = @_;
   return undef if !defined($s);
   return encode('UTF-16le', $s."\0");
}


# Inefficient. Needs a C implementation.
sub decode_LPCWSTR {
   my ($ptr) = @_;

   return undef if !$ptr;

   my $sW = '';
   while (1){
      my $chW = unpack('P2', pack(PACK_FORMAT_PTR, $ptr));
      last if $chW eq "\0\0";
      $sW .= $chW;
      $ptr += 2;
   }

   return decode('UTF-16le', $sW);
}

# -----

sub pack_SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO {
   my ($DelayedAutostart) = @_;
   return pack(PACK_FORMAT_BOOL, $DelayedAutostart ? 1 : 0);
}

# -----

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323(v=vs.85).aspx
# On error, returns false. Use $^E to get the error message.
# Close returned handle using CloseServiceHandle.
sub OpenSCManager {
   my ($MachineName, $DatabaseName, $DesiredAccess) = @_;

   my $packed_MachineName  = encode_LPCWSTR($MachineName);
   my $packed_DatabaseName = encode_LPCWSTR($DatabaseName);

   state $OpenSCManager = Win32::API->new(
      'advapi32.dll',
      'OpenSCManagerW',
      'P' . 'P' . WAPI_FORMAT_DWORD,
      WAPI_FORMAT_HANDLE,
   );

   return $OpenSCManager->Call($packed_MachineName, $packed_DatabaseName, $DesiredAccess);
}


# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx
# On error, returns false. Use $^E to get the error message.
# Close returned handle using CloseServiceHandle.
sub OpenService(
   my ($SCManager, $ServiceName, $DesiredAccess) = @_;

   my $packed_ServiceName  = encode_LPCWSTR($ServiceName);

   state $OpenService = Win32::API->new(
      'advapi32.dll',
      'OpenServiceW',
      WAPI_FORMAT_HANDLE . 'P' . WAPI_FORMAT_DWORD,
      WAPI_FORMAT_HANDLE,
   );

   return $OpenSCManager->Call($packed_MachineName, $packed_DatabaseName, $DesiredAccess);
}


# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682028(v=vs.85).aspx
# On error, returns false. Use $^E to get the error message.
sub CloseServiceHandle {
   my ($SCObject) = @_;

   state $CloseServiceHandle = Win32::API->new(
      'advapi32.dll',
      'CloseServiceHandle',
      WAPI_FORMAT_HANDLE,
      WAPI_FORMAT_BOOL,
   );

   return $CloseServiceHandle->Call($SCObject);
}


# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx
# Info must be a packed structure.
# On error, returns false. Use $^E to get the error message.
sub ChangeServiceConfig2 {
   my ($Service, $InfoLevel, $packed_Info) = @_;

   state $CloseServiceHandle = Win32::API->new(
      'advapi32.dll',
      'CloseServiceHandle',
      WAPI_FORMAT_HANDLE . WAPI_FORMAT_DWORD . 'P',
      WAPI_FORMAT_BOOL,
   );

   return $ChangeServiceConfig2->Call($Service, $InfoLevel, $packed_Info);
}

# -----

1;
```

Completely untested. In fact, I think it's buggy in 64-bit builds of Perl.

Comment: I've defined a local ppm repository so that I can install the package. But ppm repo says _Downloading LocalPackages packlist...failed 501 Protocol scheme 'c' is not supported_. Is there some tool that I need to use to initialize the repository?

Comment: I've tried to follow the guidelines at Ask Question. I'd like to use the code that ikegami provided but I'm unable to get the package installed. I'll try to find another way...

Comment: That wasn't a link to guidelines. That was a link to where you go to ask new questions.

Comment: I'll invoke the SC command from my perl script   C:\>perl C:\bat\install-the-service.pl   
added testPerlService at 20160711 00:36:46   
C:\>sc qc testperlservice   
SERVICE_NAME: testperlservice   
 START_TYPE: 2   AUTO_START   
C:\>sc config testperlservice start= delayed-auto   
C:\>sc qc testperlservice   
SERVICE_NAME: testperlservice   
 START_TYPE: 2   AUTO_START  (DELAYED)

Comment: This is no more the place to post an answer than it is the place to post a question.